# Wait for block of code before running second Swift

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am using the Async library located [here](https://github.com/duemunk/Async). My code is as follows:

```
let backgroundBlock = Async.utility {
        for serial in serialarray 
         {
        self.getVersion(serial: serial)
         }
    }



backgroundBlock.main {
            print(serialarray)
            print(versionarray)
            SwiftSpinner.hide()
    }
```

If I understand this right, getVersion should run in the background until it completes fully and then the second block should run and print out both of my arrays. Instead the first array gets printed but the second array comes up blank. I added a print inside of my getVersion function to see if it was working and I can see all the values being populated so it looks like the first block is not waiting to complete before it prints the arrays out. Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

For some additional clarity, the above code is executed in the completion handler of a simple alamofire request. And the getVersion function is as follows:

```
Alamofire.request("url=\(serial)", headers: httpheader).validate().responseData { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .success:

            if let data = response.data {

                let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)

                var count: Int = 0

                var stop = false

                for elem in xml["deviceSoftwares"]["deviceSw"].all

                {

                     for elem2 in elem["swAttrs"].all

                     {


                        if stop == false

                        {
                             count += 1

                        if (elem2["value"].element!.text) == "com.fiberlink.maas360.fpl"
                        {
                           stop = true
                        }

                        }

                    }
                }


                let position = (count/5)


                SwiftSpinner.hide()

                if stop == true

                {
                let version = xml["deviceSoftwares"]["deviceSw"][position]["swAttrs"][2]["value"].element!.text

                    versionarray.append(version)
                }

                else

                {
                    versionarray.append("N/A")


                }

                print (versionarray)

            }

        case .failure(_):

            let errorCode = response.response?.statusCode
            let errorString = String(describing: errorCode!)
            print("Error " + errorString)


        }

        }
```

**EDIT 2:**

I also tried the following:

```
let group = AsyncGroup()

                group.utility {

                    for serial in serialarray

                    {

                   self.getVersion(serial: serial)

                    }

                }

                group.wait()


                     print (serialarray)
                     print (versionarray)

                   SwiftSpinner.hide()
```

Both prints are executing before getVersion finishes its loop to populate the array.

Comment: Can we see more code? How are is versionarray declared? What does getVersion(serial: serial) look like? What function is this called in?

Comment: I added info to original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Alamofire.request` is an asynchronous call so it will return right away and therefore your method `getVersion` will return right away. You need to make `getVersion` method wait until `Alamofire.request` completes the call and versionarray is updated before continuing.